# Option, to select different type of css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically there is a option to select a css stylesheet, which to use for the website. It usually is located in side of the homepage, and it can be minimized and maximized. It is with transparent background and some color chart, also with links to website with new design. Is there any plugins that would do it for me automatically, or do I need to write it myself?

Comment: I have do idea what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Hello, for example this link - http://inksoftdesign.com/demo/colors/ click on patterns and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's some kind of plugin for this, but here's an idea. You can include all the stylesheets, and enable only one.

Here's a way to enable/disable a stylesheet that works in all browsers (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965018/512507)):

```
var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
var href = 'http://yoursite.com/foo/bar/baz.css';
for (var i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
    if (styleSheets[i].href == href) {
        styleSheets[i].disabled = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my comment on first post, you will see the patterns feature, I need something like that (the panel itself), not the css changer. Is there any easy way to include it, or I need to write it from 0?

Comment: That pattern changer on http://inksoftdesign.com/demo/colors/ is doing what alfonso has said - change the stylesheet. What it is doing is that on click of the pattern images, it's calling the function named "chooseStyle" (you can see that using Firebug). And the function itself is as follows -                                          function chooseStyle(styletitle, days){ //Interface function to switch style sheets plus save "title" attr of selected stylesheet to cookie
if (document.getElementById){
setStylesheet(styletitle)
setCookie("mysheet", styletitle, days)
}
}