# Unstyling an existing site

Tags: css, styling

I am learning CSS and want to customize an pre-existing out-of-box cookie cutter CSS style web site provided by my vendor.

Is there a way I can remove an css file which was linked in the head tag so I can strip-out/unstyle the entire page easily?

I was reading posts regarding reset.css, Normalize.css & CSS refactoring tool, not sure if they are the right tools. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried removing the line of code in which the file is called?

Comment: Just remove the `<link>` element, or re-save the files as empty files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest installing Firebug if you use Firefox so you can easily see the different stylesheets and what purpose they serve. From there just remove the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="filename.css">` element that has the styles your trying to strip and start over. Create your own file and re-insert it into the `<head>` of said site.

By your question this is all I can imagine you want to accomplish -- forgive me if I misinterpreted you ..

Here is the link to download firebug: https://getfirebug.com/downloads

Comment: I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964631/removing-link-element-with-jquery?rq=1), would you recommend doing this way?

Comment: Thanks for writing me back. I am using Firefox's disable individual css function to decide which one I want to remove. The CSS file sits on the vendor's server, so I believe the link I mentioned above is the way to go. Correct me if I'm wrong, I am learning here. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Got sidetracked, sorry about the delay! I just tried it, you are right. I can't do it! Oh no...

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the  tag in the  section, and the CSS should no longer be there, providing that all of the CSS was in fact in the CSS files and not inline.