# After a page is rendered, any way to strip out a line of HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce

Here's my issue in a nutshell.  I work for Salesforce Marketing Cloud, and we have a product called Cloud Pages.  Think of Wix or Weebly.  So basically, after publishing the page I create, there's a line of HTML code (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="someurl.css" />`) that is automatically added that is messing up my styling.  So, ideally, I need to remove this entire line that is added AFTER the fact (not by me).  Is this possible with JavaScript?

Comment: You will find your answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964631/removing-link-element-with-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as it renders in the same order every time you can use this:

```
document.styleSheets[0].disabled = true;
```

Just change it to the correct index.

Answer (score 2):

This works too.

```
var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
var href = 'http://yoursite.com/foo/bar/baz.css';
for (var i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
    if (styleSheets[i].href == href) {
        styleSheets[i].disabled = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that stripping out a stylesheet MAY not work in IE as IE wont re-render the page after it has loaded the stylesheet.

Comment: I think you can force it to rerender by changing the overflow style on particular elements..