# How to suppress or exclude CSS file from shiny header without reloading app

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny

I added a language selection radiobotton in my shiny dashboard which user can change language. For right to left languages I used a CSS file to also change the direction of dashboard to right to left direction. To do this first I used an uiOutput() function in the body of my dashboard to be used for loading my CSS files.

```
uiOutput("TagRTL")
```

In the server side I use an ovserveEvent() function to observe change of 'selected_language' returns by radioBotton. If user select "fa" language the 'bootstrap-rtl.css' file loads in the body of dashboard and hopefully the direction of dashboard could change to right to left direction without any problem. But now if user select another language which is left to right like "en" language, my expectation is the CSS files be excluded and the direction of dashboard be changed to previous status based on original bootstrap.css. But it doesn't works. I found suppressDependencies() function and I used it in }else{ expression but it does not work. How can can I handle this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
observeEvent(input$selected_language, {
   
        LANG <- input$selected_language     
        
        observe({
          if (LANG=="fa"){
            output$TagRTL<-renderUI(
              
              tags$head( tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "bootstrap-rtl.css")
                         )
            )
          }else{
          
             suppressDependencies("bootstrap-rtl.css") 
            
             
          }
        }) 
          
         
  })
```

Comment: here is th answer to your question [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965018/5448891)

Comment: Thanks Muzamil301, your link was very useful it works well...Thanks you so much.

Comment: you are welcome. please mark my comment as answer thanks